# Добавить запись в базу с id AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans, autoincrement

Работая в NetBeans. В Java новичок.

Есть таблица : id (AI) , login, password, role.

Я передаю  ему 3 значения (понимаю , что он ожидает ещё и ID)

```
insertStr = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ("
                + quotate(dlg.getLogin()) + ","
                + quotate(dlg.getPassword()) + ","
                + quotate(dlg.getRole()) + ")";
```

Как мне ему передать только эти три значения и попросить самостоятельно сгенерировать ID ?

Comment: у вас база сама генерирует id? и какую БД используете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно указать поля в которые вы передаете значения:

```
insertStr = "INSERT INTO users (login, password, role) VALUES ("
                + quotate(dlg.getLogin()) + ","
                + quotate(dlg.getPassword()) + ","
                + quotate(dlg.getRole()) + ")";
```

Comment: Спасибо , сработало .
Подскажите ещё такую штуку, я добавил несколько записей и после их удалил , у меня теперь база генерирует числа дальше а именно : 1,2, 6,7,8.

Остальные просто пропускает ,что делать ?

Comment: Решил . Если кому надо :

ALTER TABLE `table_name` PACK_KEYS =0 CHECKSUM =0 DELAY_KEY_WRITE =0 AUTO_INCREMENT =4(это число с которого начнётся счёт)